# I'm data scraping from a website and i need someone to explain this code received - JSoup

Tags: android, html, android-studio, jsoup

I got this code from Stackoverflow and while i does what i ask for, im having a hard time understanding how it does it. Im scraping certain words from a website. Just wondering if anyone can tell me exactly how its choosing the words? Particularly after the doc.select part

```
String text = doc.select("#post-15 > div > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table:not(:last-of-type)").text();
```

Comment: Could you ask this on the post where you found the code?

Comment: I just did, i never realized that i hadnt tbh

Comment: If your question is sufficiently answered, you should consider accepting the best answer and thereby mark this question as solved. If you need further help, please specify exactly what you need help with

Answer (score 2):

.select(cssQuery) takes a css query and returns an Elements object that is empty if no objects following that query are found. Scope out the docs here: (https://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

This is one way of thinking about what the css selector is doing (starting left to right on the query)

- [Find a div with an id of post-15](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)
- Get all the child divs from id="post-15"
- [Find the tables that are the 6th child element of the found div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- Get that found table's tbody element
- Find that tbody's second row (nth-child again here)
- Find that row's second column
- Find the tables that are not the last table in that column

.text() then returns the text elements of the found node.

The [css rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) in play here are:

- A > B - find child element B
- selector:nth-child(#) - the nth child of element type
- selector:last-of-type - the last child type of that element in the
- parent selector:not(x) - [represents the negation of whatever x

  is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: You beat me and your explanation is a bit more thorough than mine. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a CSS selector. A good overview over the Jsoup CSS selector syntax can be found in the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax#). Here are some clues:

```
#post-15 > div > table:nth-child(6) > 
tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > 
table:not(:last-of-type)
```

- `#id` will select the element with id `id`
- `a > b` will select element with tag b of an element with tag a
- `parent:nth-child(2)` is a so called pseudo selector. It selects the second child element of its parent
- `parent:last-of-type` is also a pseudo selector. It selects the last element of that type